# Что лучше использовать DrawElements, DrawArrays для отрисовки меша

Tags: opengl, opengles, mesh

Есть задача отрисовать меш с количеством индексов (100 000).
`DrawElements` поддерживает только unsigned short (65535) индексов.

Как лучше отрисовать такой меш через `DrawArrays` который не имеет ограничений по длинне массива с координатами вершин? Или как-то разбить меш на части и использовать `DrawElements`?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что `glDrawElements` умеет максимум 2^16 индексов? Если выберете тип `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, будет 2^32 индексов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я не заметил эту константу. Спасибо!